# Stable matching of producers, consumers and objects

Tags: algorithms, graphs, reference-request, game-theory, bipartite-matching

Has the following version of the stable matching problem been studied?

> There are $k$ types of objects.
>
> There are $n$ producers, each of whom can produce a single object of any type, and has a personal preference relation over the objects (e.g. Bob prefers to produce shoes, then socks, then cars, etc.).
>
> There are $n$ consumers, each of whom has a personal preference relation over the objects (e.g. Alice prefers to buy cars, then shoes, then socks, etc.).
>
> A *matching* is a function mapping each producer to a unique consumer and to a single object-type. I.e., each producer produces exactly one object for a single consumer.
>
> A matching is *stable* if there is no pair of producer P and consumer C such that:
>
> - P would prefer to produce a certain object X rather than the object currently produced;
> - C would prefer to consume X rather than the object currently consumed.

Does there always exist a stable matching in this setting?

Comment: Not the same, but see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem (though there the condition for optimality is something different from stability).